# Can inline AMPscript calls be commented?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm getting a scripting error when trying Send Preview:

> An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a RedirectTo function
>   call. See inner exception for details.

I've commented out, with HTML `<!--` and `-->` tags, the html blocks where these calls are found. The AMPscript is inline `(%%= =%%)`.

**Does HTML commenting not work with inline AMPscript?** It seems that the calls are still being called.

The documentation only mentions AMPscript blocks.

Answer (score 1):

It would need to wrapped in /* */.

Inline use, from how I'm reading this would require it to look like:

> > %%[/*=VALUE=*/]%%.

When you're ready to un-comment, remove [/* and */].

Comment: So    <a href="%%/*=RedirectTo(<object>)=*/%%" ?

Comment: No, you still need the brackets -- as in the example

Comment: Thanks; I've wrapped all RedirectTo() calls in /* */, using brackets, but I'm still getting the error. Where can I view the inner exception details?